# How to sort one csv file according to a second file?

Tags: python, csv, awk

I have two files

F1

```
bar
foo
egg
```

F2

```
"egg","apple","green"
"egg","orange","red"
"egg","apple","green"
"bar","spam","orange"
"bar","orange","blue"
"bacon","red","orange"
"foo","apple","green"
"foo","blue","apple"
"spam","apple","yellow"
"spam","green","egg"
```

and I'd like to sort F2 according to F1, every line in F2 with a first element that is not present in F1 should be added at the end of the resulting list. So that I get:

```
"bar","spam","orange"
"bar","orange","blue"
"foo","apple","green"
"foo","blue","apple"
"egg","apple","green"
"egg","orange","red"
"egg","apple","green"
"bacon","red","orange"
"spam","apple","yellow"
"spam","green","egg"
```

I'd love a python3 solution. But am also open for a solution in awk.

Comment: something like `sorted(the_list, key=lambda x: int(x not in other_list))`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: it will be good if you show your solution.

Comment: None of your F2 lines present in F1. Do you mean element?

Comment: yes element, fixed it

Comment: Are you only interested in the value in the first field of F2 or across all fields? If the latter then clarify the behavior for multiple matches. Are you looking for string or regexp matches? Are partial matches OK or only whole field matches?

Comment: yes, only the first element should be considered for sorting the lines

Comment: That answers 1 question, what about the rest? Please update your question to include all relevant information and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @user430, please always do add what you have tried also in your post as we all here to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you. Assuming that you want to do match of 1st field of 1st field of F2 file with F1 file's first field(which has only 1 field itself as per shown samples)

```
awk -F'"' '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=(a[$2]?a[$2] ORS:"")$0;
  b[$2];
  next
}
($0 in b){
  print a[$0];
  c[$0]
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(!(i in c)){ print a[i] }
}}' F2  F1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1=['bar','foo','egg']

list2=[["egg","apple","green"],
    ["egg","orange","red"],
    ["egg","apple","green"],
    ["bar","spam","orange"],
    ["bar","orange","blue"],
    ["bacon","red","orange"],
    ["foo","apple","green"],
    ["foo","blue","apple"],
    ["spam","apple","yellow"],
    ["spam","green","egg"]]

list_to_sort=[]
list_not_to_sort=[]
for element in list2:
    if(element[0].split(',')[0] in list1):
        list_to_sort.append(element)
    else:
        not_to_sort.append(element)
list_to_sort.sort()
print(list_to_sort+not_to_sort)
```

**Output:**

```
[['bar', 'orange', 'blue'],
 ['bar', 'spam', 'orange'],
 ['egg', 'apple', 'green'],
 ['egg', 'apple', 'green'],
 ['egg', 'orange', 'red'],
 ['foo', 'apple', 'green'],
 ['foo', 'blue', 'apple'],
 ['bacon', 'red', 'orange'],
 ['spam', 'apple', 'yellow'],
 ['spam', 'green', 'egg']]
```